# How can I start a CustomClipper (ClipPath) from top right and NOT top left

Tags: flutter, dart

My CustomClipper is going from the top left corner, but, I want it to start from the top right.
Here's my code:
The Clipper:

```
class ProfileBarClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 50);
    var controllPoint = Offset(50, size.height);
    var endPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        controllPoint.dx, controllPoint.dy, endPoint.dx, endPoint.dy);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The usage of ProfileBarClipper():

```
ClipPath(
    clipper: ProfileBarClipper(),
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 200,
    ),
)
```

And here's an image of this code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVsL3.png

Comment: Did you use [moveTo()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/moveTo.html) method in path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `moveTo`.

Like this.

```
var path = new Path();
path.moveTo(size.width,0); // (size.width, 0) means top right
```

UPDATE: Check this out...

```
class ProfileBarClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 50);
    var controllPoint = Offset(size.width-50, size.height);
    var endPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        controllPoint.dx, controllPoint.dy, endPoint.dx, endPoint.dy);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't work. I added path.moveTo(size.width, 0) right after creating the var path, and it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is the line is still going to the left